# Eclipse Juno- Suddenly “cannot run program 'make' : unknow reason”

Tags: eclipse, makefile, eclipse-cdt

I'm using Eclipse JUNO for developing C applications. It runs on Ubuntu 12.04 inside a 3-CPU, 1GiB RAM virtual machine.

Everything works perfectly, but sometimes, I cannot build my application any more and the following error occurs:"cannot run program make; unknown reason".

Any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Apparently this error is due to low memory conditions. It mostly occurs after searching in files within Eclipse (a search that returns a large result set). If the error occurs again:

- Re-start Eclipse and try again
- If it does not fix the problem, you need to completely reboot the OS

Comment: I found this solution working for eclipse Mars CDT. Thanks

Comment: Sometimes it helps to just run the garbage collector, instead of restarting eclipse